# How can I repeatedly send the contents of a file via socat / ncat to a socket

Tags: networking, performance, netcat, socat, nc

I'm running some performance testing, and I'm trying to send the same file repeatedly to a socket.

If I do something like:

```
$ socat -b1048576 -u OPEN:/dev/zero TCP4-LISTEN:9899,reuseaddr,fork 
$ socat -b1048576 -u TCP:127.0.0.1:9899 OPEN:/dev/null
```

Then with that 1MB buffer `iftop` tells me that I'm pushing 20Gbps.

However, what I'm really trying to do is something more like:

```
$ socat -b1048576 -u OPEN:somefile.dat TCP4-LISTEN:9899,reuseaddr,fork 
$ myprog TCP:127.0.0.1:9899 > /dev/null
```

But it only pushes that `somefile.dat` one time, I'd really like it to `rewind()` to the beginning and send it again.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you want to open and send the same file at each new connection, you can use `-U`, the reverse direction to `-u`, and the reversed addresses, as in the following

```
socat -b1048576 -U TCP4-LISTEN:9899,reuseaddr,fork OPEN:somefile.dat
socat TCP:127.0.0.1:9899 - >/dev/null
```

---

If you want the file to repeat *ad infinitum*, you can use something like this:

```
socat -b1048576 -U TCP4-LISTEN:9899,reuseaddr,fork SYSTEM:'while cat somefile.dat;do \: ;done'
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I wanted, but it does force the client to reconnect each time.

Comment: @Alun if you want an infinite file, like `/dev/zero` you can add a loop, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's the best that can be done. Was really hoping for something that would be functionally equivalent to `while(1) sendfile(soc, file, 0, size);` for maximum performance...